# How to display binary data as image - extjs 4

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, extjs4

Here is the binary for a valid .JPEG image.
<s>http://pastebin.ca/raw/2314500</s>

I have tried to use Python to save this binary data into an image.

How can I convert this data to a viewable .JPEG image with extjs 4?

I tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,+ binary data
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Need to convert it in base64.

JS have btoa() function for it.

For example:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + btoa('your-binary-data');
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

But i think what your binary data in pastebin is invalid - the jpeg data must be ended on 'ffd9'.

**Update:**

Need to write simple hex to base64 converter:

```
function hexToBase64(str) {
    return btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, str.replace(/\r|\n/g, "").replace(/([\da-fA-F]{2}) ?/g, "0x$1 ").replace(/ +$/, "").split(" ")));
}
```

And use it:

```
img.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + hexToBase64('your-binary-data');
```

See working example with your hex data on [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/79NnG/)

Comment: ya.the binary data are end with ffd9,just ignore the 00 bytes

Comment: i have delete the end of 00 bytes,but still can't work,can't display image

Comment: thanks @Vlad ! i never found this kind of solution on google.com thanks a lot !

Comment: Jsfiddle is Exactly what I needed

Comment: Thank you very much @Vlad i am searching on goggle from last 3 days for such solution.. it works for me as expected.. thanks a lot.. keep rocking \m/

Comment: You are truly awesome. Thank you very much

Comment: That's nice, but performance costly if done in a highly refreshed part of the UI. Any way to avoid base64 ?

Comment: Is there a way to send binary image data without converting it to a string?

Answer (score 4):

The data URI format is:

> `data:<headers>;<encoding>,<data>`

So, you need only append your data to the "data:image/jpeg;," string:

```
var your_binary_data = document.body.innerText.replace(/(..)/gim,'%$1'); // parse text data to URI format

window.open('data:image/jpeg;,'+your_binary_data);
```

Answer (score 1):

In ExtJs, you can use

> xtype: 'image'

to render a image.

Here is a fiddle showing rendering of binary data with extjs.

atob -- > converts ascii to binary

btoa -- > converts binary to ascii

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        var srcBase64 = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + btoa(atob("iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mP8H8hYDwAFegHS8+X7mgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="));

        Ext.create("Ext.panel.Panel", {
            title: "Test",
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            height: 400,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'image',
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                src: srcBase64
            }]
        })
    }
});
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/28h0

Answer (score -3):

In front-end JavaScript/HTML, you can load a binary file as an image, you do not have to convert to base64:

```
<img src="http://engci.nabisco.com/artifactory/repo/folder/my-image">
```

my-image is a binary image file. This will load just fine.

Comment: The question is about displaying an image when it isn't in a file

Comment: This about displaying binary data