# Showing image with javascript from C# byteArray

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, activex

I have a C# method (that is an ActiveX component that runs on the client) that returns a photo.
On C# side I have two properties:

```
public byte[] Photo { get; set; }
public string PhotoString { get; set; }
```

The string version is gotten by simple conversion with System.Convert.ToBase64String().

Now I need a way to show that photo using javascript. I tried using the code from this answer:
[How to display binary data as image - extjs 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915058/how-to-display-binary-data-as-image-extjs-4/14918390#14918390)

with

```
$("#imgUserImage").attr("src", 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + hexToBase64(data.PhotoString));
```

But that didn't work. Also if I copy my string to the fiddle in that answer it's not working so I'm assuming the problem is in the string.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's already encoded properly, you don't need to call `hexToBase64()`.

```
$("#imgUserImage").attr("src", 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+data.PhotoString);
```

[Demo in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VFnqE/1/)

Comment: wow that simple!? Thanks it worked. I can't accept your answer for 6 more minutes but I'll do it.

Comment: Thanks ! FYI, I encoded using this site http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp