# How to show a Image Binary String in javascript?

Tags: javascript, image-processing

How to show a Image Binary String in javascript?
I have no idea how can I convert to image URL. Is it possible?
(In my case, I can use FileReader, Blob, URL.createObjectURL)

```
var img = new Image();
var img.src = '[URL]';
```

data is like this..

```
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
```

Comment: not sure what you're asking, did you mean http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme ?

Comment: I need to convert my data (starting with /tf/ like this) for web site.

Comment: This might help too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915058/how-to-display-binary-data-as-image-extjs-4