# Trouble displaying binary stored in Azure Blob Storage on webpage

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-blob-storage

Using Windows Azure storage services, I have created a container and subsequently created a BlockBlob (a JPEG image) using the PUT Rest API. I can log into my Azure portal and download the image.

When I call the [GET API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179440.aspx) Azure successfully returns me the blob in the response body -- and I think it's the same raw binary I uploaded.

When I call the GET API, I'm doing so via an XHR request in my JavaScript (Sencha Touch) application. I can see the response (the raw binary), but I cannot figure out how to read the binary into an image that I can display.

I've tried the following:

```
rawBinary = response.responseText;
encodedBinary = btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(rawBinary)));
img.setSrc('data:' + file.type + ';base64,' + encodedBinary);
```

...which gives me something like this:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,77+977+977+977+9ABBKRklGAAEBAAABAAEAAO+/ve+/vQBYRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgAAgESAAMAAAABAAEAAO+/vWkABAAAAAEAAAAmAAAAAAAD77+9AQADAAAAAQABAADvv70CAAQAAAABAAAKIO+/vQMABAAAAAEAAAfvv70AAAAA77.......
```

This correctly sets a background URL on a DIV as a base64 encoded image... but nothing displays. It *looks* like a valid base64 string, and there are no errors in my console or network tabs. But nothing shows.

Can anyone help?

**EDIT:** Below is what the "binary" response looks like in the XHR response body:

```
����JFIF��XExifMM*�i&��
����C   ��C��� "��  
���}!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br� 

...etc... VERY long response of unreadable characters
```

Comment: does your div and/or img have height/width specified?

Comment: Yes, I can verify in Safari Web Inspector that the DIV has a height and width.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this jsfiddle by [Vlad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2004123/vlad) - http://jsfiddle.net/79NnG/

```
function hexToBase64(str) {
    return btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, str.replace(/\r|\n/g, "").replace(/([\da-fA-F]{2}) ?/g, "0x$1 ").replace(/ +$/, "").split(" ")));
}

var img = new Image();
img.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64,"+hexToBase64(getBinary());
alert(hexToBase64(getBinary()));
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

Also this post should help you - [How to display binary data as image - extjs 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915058/how-to-display-binary-data-as-image-extjs-4)

Comment: Using the hexToBase64() method, I end up with a very different base64 string... but ultimately still no image displayed.

Comment: To be clear, Safari Web Inspector does NOT throw an error saying: "Failed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on this server." It just appears as a broken image.

Comment: can you try simply btoa(binary data)?

Comment: I get "Error: InvalidCharacterError: DOM Exception 5" when I try that. I updated my original post with a sample of the response body.