# How to Load an image stored in MS SQL Server 2012 as Image data type into nodejs server then rendering in Client webpage in <img> tag

Tags: node.js, json, image, express, sql-server-2012

[After query execution The image data in console.log]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KR3m5.jpg

Comment: Please help me immediately....

Comment: what is your approach, what methods have you tried, share some backdrop of your work

Comment: Does this help you ? [https://stackoverflow.com/a/41059247/6534338](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41059247/6534338)