# Display raw image data from response

Tags: javascript, html

I have API url, that send me in response an image.
When i try to console.log my response i see something like that:

[image: Response with image in console]

Please tell me what is the best way to display that raw-data in my page?
What format of raw-data is it? I can not even google it, because I really don`t know what format is it.

```js
const img = document.createElement('img');
document.body.appendChild(img);

const src = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png/280px-PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png';

fetch(src)
  .then(resp => resp.blob())
  .then(blob => URL.createObjectURL(blob))
  .then(uri => (img.src = uri));
```

```html
<!-- Polyfill for older browsers -->
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/github/fetch/master/fetch.js"></script>
```

Comment: it's just the binary image data displayed as text, I'd imagine. Same as you'd get if you tried to open the file in Notepad or something. Why did you expect to be able to view an image in a text-based console?

Comment: thx for clarification. but he might have trouble receiving binary data without encoding it (for example in base64), as some chars turns out to be invalid for requests. just saying

Comment: @Kaddath there seems to be no trouble receiving it, only a misunderstanding about the context in which the data might be displayed or used

Comment: Do you want to display the byte values (in hexadecimal) that represent each pixel; in a two-dimensional array?

Comment: I do not try to view my image in console. I just get image in raw and want to understand how can i work with that image.

Comment: Just talking from my experience, i also used the word "might" for a reason.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl i tried to convert it to base64. But I am not sure, is it hex-data or something else.
I think, converting it to base64 will solve my problem.

Comment: "want to understand how can i work with that image". Well what do you actually want to do with it, really? Did you download it via an ajax request? There's not much you can do with it in that context. If you want to display the image in your page, create an img tag and set the src to the URL of your API where you download the image.

Comment: @ADyson I get it by request with parameters

Comment: If you want to DISPLAY the image, don't print the image data to the console. Wrap the returned request in a `Content-type` of `image/png`. Lookup "HTML page headers".

Comment: Does this help?
https://jsbin.com/kadopelanu/edit?js,output

Comment: That JS Bin example works... I am including it in your post.

Comment: @Vivek yep, I think i can use it, thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display binary data as image - extjs 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915058/how-to-display-binary-data-as-image-extjs-4)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915058/how-to-display-binary-data-as-image-extjs-4).

The basic premise would be to base64 encode using `btoa` and then add it to the page, like so:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = 'data:image/png;base64,' + btoa('your-binary-data');
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

Comment: Thanks, I think it is what i was looking for