# Displaying a PNG from a REST API that is not from a URL

Tags: http, dart, flutter

I have a REST endpoint that, when I consume it (GET endpoint that requires a few headers), it returns an image, but not a URL. Using Postman, I get a raw response as follows:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 07 Aug 2018 21:26:33 GMT
Server: Apache
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, HEAD
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Origin, X-c2b-Authorization, X-c2b-mTAN, X-Requested-With, X-c2b-Sender-Id, Content-Type, Accept, Cache-Control
Max-Forwards: 20
Via: 3.1 lp10b2wxdpp02 (Some Random Gateway)
X-CorrelationID: Id-880e6a5b74d00f00000000008ee4edd1 0
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-NodeID: 02
X-Powered-By: JOY
Content-Type: image/png
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

PNG
...
```

I have checked this recipe from the Flutter site: https://flutter.io/cookbook/images/network-image/ However, it assumes that you are passing a URL, which I cannot do given the response. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: How are you getting the image if it doesn't have a url?

Comment: I mean, yes using postman, but wouldn't that API be a url?

Comment: can u provide the link?

Comment: This question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915058/how-to-display-binary-data-as-image-extjs-4 - the answer tells you how to create an image html element from binary data (which you will get from your GET request)