# How to GET image from flask with axios

Tags: javascript, python, flask, axios, multipartform-data

that's my flask test route which should give image:

```
@app.route('/marknext', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def marknext():
    id = request.form.get("ID")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return "OK"
    else:
        image_file_path = '/home/cnd/contrib/python/input/ChinaSet_AllFiles/CXR_png/CHNCXR_0370_1.png'
        # res = make_response(send_file(image_file_path, add_etags=False, cache_timeout=0))
        # return res
        return send_file(image_file_path, add_etags=False, cache_timeout=0, attachment_filename='CHNCXR_0370_1.png')
```

and on client side I'm trying to get that file with axios and put it into `<img>`

```
  axios.get('/marknext', {
    params: {
      ID: 0
    }
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    var reader = new window.FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(response.data); 
    reader.onload = function() {
      var imageDataUrl = reader.result;
      $("#selected-image").attr("src", imageDataUrl)
    }
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
  .then(function () {
    // always executed
  });
```

And I'm getting my Error on console:

```
TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.
    at mark.js:14
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you check what `response.data` is? `console.log(response.data)`

Comment: @DiogoSgrillo not sure, how?

Comment: Right before `reader.readAsDataURL` add the `console.log(response.data)`

Comment: it's starting with PNG, looks like binary

Comment: Can I ask why you want to do this in the first place? Why not set `src` to the image URL and let the browser load the file?

Comment: not fully sure but file should get there from different places, maybe I can change target image on hard drive and not html src

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not much experience with Axios, but some Googling lead me to a similar question asked in the [ReactJS subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/bifsrt/display_image_from_flask_send_file_function/). It seems like you need to initialize a `Blob` using `response.data` then pass that to `readAsDataURL()` instead of the `response` directly.

```js
.then(function (response) {
    var responseBlob = new Blob([response.data], {type:"image/png"}); 
    var reader = new window.FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(responseBlob); 
    reader.onload = function() {
      var imageDataUrl = reader.result;
      $("#selected-image").attr("src", imageDataUrl)
    }
  })
```

Comment: it helps! at least partially, now there is no error but image is not showing either, if I insepct page I see `src=data:image/ong;base64, ..... ` and large binary blob but it's not showing

Comment: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915058/how-to-display-binary-data-as-image-extjs-4)

Comment: I've checked answer and was trying some random picks from it, it didn't help