# How to show image from unicode ajax responseText?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get image from ajax, but i get result unicode. but in inspect network result my image display. I get result like this

```
����JFIFHH��C↵↵↵
```

How to display image from unicode like this?

this is my ajax code

```
$.ajax({
        url: urlpath,
        headers: {
            authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem(access_token)}`,
        },
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(response, status, xhr) {
            $(".img-profile-report").attr("src", `data:image/png;base64,${hexToBase64(response)}`);
            console.log(response);
            console.log('aaa')
        },
        error: function(response, status, xhr) {
            console.log('bbb');
            console.log(response);
            // localStorage.clear();
            // window.location = "/login";
        },
    });
```

Comment: Well how are you getting it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display binary data as image - extjs 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915058/how-to-display-binary-data-as-image-extjs-4) (Ignore the library tag, the answer is vanilla js)

Comment: not working using btoa

Comment: `dataType: "text"` might not be the best way of getting an *image*.

Comment: I get error ``` Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window': The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.``` if using btoa

Comment: then what is the best solution? I used the image / jpeg dataType not working